# Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap. [Switching to Thread 6]

Tags: c, gdb, remote-debugging

I know this question has been asked before, but I have read all the threads and I didn't find an answer.
From the moment I execure `run` to start debugging my project, I get this : `Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap. [Switching to Thread 6]`. When I do `ctrl+c`, gdb tells me : `Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00000000 in ?? ()`

Usually it'll tell me which file and which function it got interrupted at not `0x00000000 in ?? ()`
GDB no longer hits breakpoints, and what makes matter crazier is the fact that a colleague and I, are sharing the same session (the debug is done using cygwin with a remote machine) and it works fine for them but not for me.
when I try to get info about the threads using `info threads` here's what I get :

```
[New Thread 20]
 [New Thread 21]
 [New Thread 22]
  Id   Target Id         Frame
  4    Thread 22 (ssp=0xa9004d5c) 0x00000000 in ?? ()
  3    Thread 21 (ssp=0xa9002e64) 0x00000010 in ?? ()
  2    Thread 20 (ssp=0xa9000ef4) 0x00000000 in ?? ()

The current thread <Thread ID 1> has terminated.  See `help thread'
```

there's no thread 6, there's no `*` to indicate which thread gdb is using. And I don't even know if that's linked to the problem.
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You are *again* withholding nearly all relevant info.

Comment: By "sharing the same session", does that mean that multiple users are running their own copy of gdb (same or different versions?) and taking turns connecting to the same remote gdbserver process?

Comment: When i say the same session, I mean that the two of us are logged in as the same user. As for the gdb version, it 7.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not providing *nearly* enough info to help you. Details *matter*, and you are withholding them. Versions of GDB and gdbserver matter, how you invoke GDB and gdbserver matter, what warnings you receive from GDB (if any) matter.

Now, this error message:

```
Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap. [Switching to Thread 6]
```

usually means that gdbserver has not attached one of the threads of your process, and that thread has tried to execute breakpoint instruction (you do have breakpoints set before this happens, don't you?).

One of the reasons this may happen is when your GDB loads "wrong" `libthread_db.so` (one that doesn't match the target `libc.so.6`).

> what makes matter crazier is the fact that a colleague and I, are sharing the same session (the debug is done using cygwin with a remote machine) and it works fine for them but not for me.

I am not sure what you mean by "same session", but it's probably not "when he types commands, they work; but when I type the same commands into the same GDB, they don't".

One difference between you and your colleague could be `LD_LIBRATY_PATH` environment variable setting. Another could be in `~/.gdbinit` or in `./.gdbinit`.

I suggest running `gdb -nx` to get rid of the latter, and unsetting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to get rid of the former.

Comment: When i say the same session, I mean that the two of us are logged in as the same user on the same machine.  As for the gdb version, it's 7.2.

Comment: What if I am not debugging and not setting any break points? This puzzles me.

Comment: @ed22 If you are not debugging, then you by definition can't receive the GDB message which is the subject of this question. You should ask a separate one, and provide details of what _exactly_ you are doing.

Comment: @EmployedRussian I have compiled the app and am trying to run it. I am getting this error. No debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the whole thing and for some reason no one seemed to notice it is this : 
this is how I call gdb `/usr/local/build/gdbx.y/gdb/gdb` what I should be doing is this :  `/usr/local/build/gdbx.y/build/gdb/gdb`
It was a path problem.

Comment: After a local `gdb` install you usually find `gdb` at `/usr/local/bin/gdb`. Something sounds a bit unusual.